# adding form styling to django forms

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I am currently in the process of adding a theme to the admin of django one issue I have found it adding styling to the forms is that it is very difficult and I can't find much useful documentation on it. The only real thing I need to do is add classes to the form elements so that they match the theme I am using is this possible and if so how would you go about doing it the code I am currently using is very basic and the basic code included in the standard theme does anybody know how to add classes to these standard bits of code bellow is what I have.

```
  {% if is_popup %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_popup" value="1" />
  {% endif %}
  {% if save_on_top %}
        {% block submit_buttons_top %}
            {% submit_row %}
        {% endblock %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if errors %}
        <p class="errornote">
                {% blocktrans count counter=errors|length %}
                     Please correct the error below.
                     {% plural %}
                     Please correct the errors below.
                {% endblocktrans %}
        </p>
        {{ adminform.form.non_field_errors }}
  {% endif %}

 {% block field_sets %}
        {% for fieldset in adminform %}
                {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
        {% endfor %}
 {% endblock %}

 {% block after_field_sets %}{% endblock %}

 {% block inline_field_sets %}
        {% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
                {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
        {% endfor %}
 {% endblock %}

 {% block after_related_objects %}{% endblock %}

 {% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
        {% submit_row %}
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but certainly one way would be to overwrite all the widgets in your ModelAdmin rather than in the template.  That could look something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.extras.widgets import TextInput

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'class':'my-widget-class'},)},
    }
```

You'd have to go through and do that for each widget, but then they'd have the appropriate classes -- at least for that modelAdmin.

Comment: Just wondering but where would the best place be to put this file does it need to go in an specific place.

Comment: Yeah, this code would have to go in the admin.py file for whatever relevant app.  I assume most of your models have a modelAdmin in their admin.py file, so you would want to add the formfield_overrides for each of those.  More information [in the docs].(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides)

Comment: OK so there is no way to do a global change I can only change it for each individual model.

Comment: Oh, no. I'm not going to go so far as to say there is NO way to do it globally. But one didn't immediately come to my mind, and as a stopgap measure this method should work.

Comment: Ok thanks sorry to bother you again but what if I want to apply this to a models like the default user model

Comment: No worries.  You can actually extend the default, built-in UserAdmin.  It would be hard to format the code for that properly in a comment, but if you look at [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) you should be able to see how it's done.  You'd just add the formfield_overrides to your new UserAdmin class, and it _should_ work.  I haven't tested that myself, though.

Comment: Great!  Should you happen to come across a more universal solution, you should post it here as an answer.  I'd be curious to see it.